# Why does 1+1 work, but not other methods, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, it's possible to rewrite `1.+(1)` as `1 + 1`. However, it's not possible to do this for other methods, such as `1.to_s`, and rewrite them as `1to_s` or `1 to_s`. Why is this?

In other words, why is it possible to call `1+1` but not for other methods? Is this, among other methods, a nicety that's allowed by the interpreter?

Note that this works for other math operators/methods such as `/` and `**`.

Comment: I know little about Ruby, but is `1.+(1)` *actually* calling a method? Or does it break down to `1.0 + 1` ?

Comment: Yes, it is a method. If you call `1.methods` in the interpreter, you'll get among others, `:+`. You can also rewrite the `+` method, and can define it on other classes that wouldn't traditionally have a `+` method.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Nope, other way around, `1 + 1` breaks down to `1.+(1)`

Comment: @paxdiablo, Ruby coming from Smalltalk, where the primitive is the *message*, I would guess, `1 + 1` is just sugar for `1.+(1)` - as @Jeremy commented.

Comment: Fair enough. Very interesting, as what I described is in fact the way this expression is handled in Python.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart In Python it breaks down to `(1).__add__(1)` (or maybe there is some special casing for ints) *EDIT* Well apparently it gets just folded into the constant `2` :P

Comment: @NiklasB. Fair enough. But the syntax in question, `1.+(1)` *is* behaving (at the "next" step down) as I mentioned: `1.0 + 1`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I see what you mean now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a + b` is just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the method call `a.+(b)` (and the same is true for the other operators). This transformation is done during parsing. You can see it [here, in ruby's bison grammar](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/dcd1e5e5c298b35899c962985b4d195781c6397d/parse.y). In particular, the [rule for `a + b`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/dcd1e5e5c298b35899c962985b4d195781c6397d/parse.y#L2070) uses `call_bin_op` to construct the abstract syntax tree node to return, which is [a macro that forwards to `call_bin_op_gen`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/dcd1e5e5c298b35899c962985b4d195781c6397d/parse.y#L409), which [calls `NEW_CALL`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/dcd1e5e5c298b35899c962985b4d195781c6397d/parse.y#L8534), which [builds an AST node representing a method call](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/dcd1e5e5c298b35899c962985b4d195781c6397d/node.h#L429).

Answer (score 1):

As you state: "In Ruby, everything is an object", therefore all the things you can *do* end up being method calls. There is some syntactic sugar involved in making `1+1` call the `#+()` method of the `Fixnum` object `1` (you actually cannot define this yourselves as pointed out by @Ismail Badawi, it is part of the ruby language definition).

However as `to_s` already *is* a method call there is not much you can do about it. You may call it as `1.to_s()`, but it is only possible to omit the `.` if there is no ambiguity involved and there is bound to be some in your example.

Comment: In fact you can omit the `.` only for certain hardcoded function names like `*`, `+` etc

Comment: You are most probably correct, `RSpec` magic made me believe otherwise, but that is probably just inside a block or as part of the parameters.

Comment: Well you can leave away parentheses in many situations and you can include modules into the global namespace, so you can write `describe X, "foo"` instead of `receiver.describe(X,"foo")`